# Json Structure is So Different unable to change that to Java Objects

Tags: java, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, gson

I am working on facebook application.  When i queried for `https://graph.facebook.com/me/video.watches?offset=0&limit=1000` I am getting a List of Watched Movies.  For eg. I am pasting only one movie out of that list here.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "664878940211923", 
      "data": {
        "tv_show": {
          "id": "108611845829948", 
          "url": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Popeye-the-Sailor/108611845829948", 
          "type": "video.tv_show", 
          "title": "Popeye the Sailor"
        }
      }, 
      "type": "video.watches", 
    },
```

Here is the POJO Class I created to convert this to Java.

```
import java.util.List;

public class FBUserVideoWatches {
    private List<Data> data;

    public List<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public class Data{
        private long id;
        private TVData data;
        private String type;

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public TVData getData() {
            return data;
        }
        public void setData(TVData data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

    public class TVData{
        private TV_Shows tv_shows;

        public TV_Shows getTv_shows() {
            return tv_shows;
        }

        public void setTv_shows(TV_Shows tv_shows) {
            this.tv_shows = tv_shows;
        }
    }
    public class TV_Shows{
        private long id;
        private String url;
        private String type;
        private String title;

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }
        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how i convert the json to java.

```
FBUserVideoWatches fbUserVideoWatches = gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), FBUserVideoWatches.class);

            for (Data data : fbUserVideoWatches.getData()) {
                System.out.println(data.getId());//This only works and I am getting values.
                if(null != data.getData()){ 
                    if(null!=data.getData().getTv_shows()){
                        System.out.print(data.getData().getTv_shows().getTitle());
                    }
                    if(null!=data.getData().getTv_shows()){
                        System.out.print(data.getData().getTv_shows().getType());
                    }
                }
            }
```

When I use getter methods to get data from java class I am getting `ID 664878940211923` & `"type": "video.watches"` as shown above. The members inside `"tv_show"` I am unable to access.  I think some where I went wrong in creating POJO.  I am unable to find that mistake.  Please help me what corrections is necessary to make that work.  Hope my question is clear.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can just simple print `fbUserVideoWatches` after the first line to check the identity after json conversion.

Comment: Problem is not that I suspect.  Because I am able to print data.getId() from java after parsing Json. I think the problem with class TVData and TV_Shows Class which is not mapped correctly with Json I think.

Comment: I check the gson document, I think the problem is the collection member of `FBUserVideoWatches`, and I guess [JsonParser](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/extras/examples/rawcollections/RawCollectionsExample.java) may give you some hints.

Comment: @EnginePai: As you said Gson is not problem.  The problem with my class, the way I created it.  Can you get some idea out of that where I went wrong on creation of POJO.

Comment: I've checked your POJO twice and no problem was found, so I think the problem is the process of conversion from json to java collection. This is why I suggest that you can give a try to use `JsonParser` instead of `gson.fromJson`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were doing mistake in TVData Class your forgot serialized name on instance property coz its in diffferent in json and TV data class

```
@SerializedName(value="tv_show")
private TV_Shows tv_shows;
```

Assuming your json is like this

```
{
 "data":[
      {
         "id":"664878940211923",
         "data":{
            "tv_show":{
               "id":"108611845829948",
               "url":"https://www.facebook.com/pages/Popeye-the-Sailor/108611845829948",
               "type":"video.tv_show",
               "title":"Popeye the Sailor"
            }
         },
         "type":"video.watches"
      },
      {
         "id":"664878940211923",
         "data":{
            "tv_show":{
               "id":"108611845829948",
               "url":"https://www.facebook.com/pages/Popeye-the-Sailor/108611845829948",
               "type":"video.tv_show",
               "title":"Popeye the Sailor"
            }
         },
         "type":"video.watches"
      }
   ]
}
```

Parsing model will like below according you to your json format

```
public class FBUserVideoWatches {

    private List<Data> data;

    public List<Data> getData() { return data; }

    public void setData(List<Data> data) {  this.data = data;}
}


public class Data {

    private TVData data;

    private String id;
    private String type;

// setter/getter here
}

public class TVData {

    @SerializedName(value="tv_show")
    private Show show;
// setter/getter here
}

public class Show {

    private String id;
    private String url;
    private String type;
    private String title;
       // setter/getter here
   }
```

finally with Google Gson parse your object as like below

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
FBUserVideoWatches fbUserVideoWatches =gson.fromJson(json_string, FBUserVideoWatches.class);
```